# Calculate max even lengths of a string to be split

Tags: c++, string, split

I know what I want but I have no idea if there's a technical name for this or how to go about calculating it.

Suppose I have a string:

`ABCDEFGHI`

This string can be split evenly into a "MAXIMUM" of 3 characters each sub-string.

Basically, I'm trying to find out how to split a string evenly into its maximum sub-lengths. A string of 25 characters can be evenly split into 5 parts consisting of 5 characters each. If I tried to split it into 4 or 6 pieces, I'd have an odd length string (a string with a size different from the others).

- A string of 9 characters can be split into only 3 pieces of 3 characters each.
- A string of 10 characters can be split into only 2 pieces of 5 characters each.
- A string of 25 characters can be split into only 5 pieces of 5 characters each.
- A string of 15 characters can be split into 3 pieces of 5 characters each OR 5 pieces of 3 characters each.
- A string of 11 characters **cannot** be split because one string will always be larger than the other.

So how do I go about doing this? I've thought of using the square root but that doesn't work for a string of "10" characters. Works for 9 and 25 just fine.

Any ideas? Is there a technical name for such a thing? I thought of "Greatest Common Divisor", but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well... let me see... I think that if I got it right, you want to verify if a certain number (the length of your string) is prime or not :)

A first idea would be this:
1) get length of string, make a loop where you divide the length of the string by all numbers from 2 up to (length of string/2) [you will need to check if this (length of string/2) is a whole number too, and adjust it if not ;)]
2) if at least ONE number divides it, bam. (You check this one by verifying if there is a remainder after the division)
3) if not, you got yourself a prime. Sorry, no even division.

Of course that approach would not be very fast for very long strings... just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is only about prime number and composite number, a basic math concept. The algorithm you need is [Primality Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)